# Add more than one gradient in border-image?

Tags: html, css, border, border-image

For `background-image` you can add as many `radial-gradient` and/or `linear-gradient` you want. But for `border-image` it seems like you can only add one. If find it quite strange, because the principle of how to display gradients should be the same for border and background, right?

Is there a way to add more than one gradient in `border-image`? I'm only interested in a pure CSS solution.

This doesn't work, because it contains more than 1 gradient:

```
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px; 
  border: 50px solid black;
  border-image: 
  radial-gradient(circle at 20px 30px, green 20px, rgba(0,0,255, .5) 20px),
  radial-gradient(30deg, blue 22px, red 22px);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/p6r2p78g/

This works, but contains only one gradient:

```
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 50px solid black;
  border-image: radial-gradient(circle at 20px 30px, green 20px, rgba(0, 0, 255, .5) 20px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/p6r2p78g/1/

Comment: Seems to me you have your answer...No, you can't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you can't set more than one image to the `border-image` shorthand or the `border-image-source` longhand property.

As per spec for [`border-image-source`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-image-source), we can see that only one image layer is specified as value.

> Name: border-image-source
>
> Value:    none | <image>

whereas for [`background-image`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering), we can see that multiple layers are specified.

> Name: background-image
>
> Value:    <bg-image> [ , <bg-image> ]*

Below is an extract from the [spec which introduces layering of background images](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering): (emphasis mine)

> The background of a box can have multiple layers in CSS3. The ***number of layers is determined by the number of comma-separated values*** in the ‘background-image’ property.

Answer (score 0):

Just stubled upon this question when I was looking for the same thing.
But for other people, trying this:

You could just add a pseudo-element, and give that one a border too.
Guessing you would use transparent, because otherwise multiple gradients wouldn't be visible at all.

I've got the following:

```
h1{
    --border-width: 5px;

    border-width: var(--border-width);
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff0000, transparent 20%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    font-size: 5rem;
    position: relative;
}
h1::after{
    position: absolute;
    inset: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    content: '';
    background: transparent;
    border-width: var(--border-width);
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 80%, #ff0000 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

I set the inset of the pseudo element to negative the border-width to make sure it aligns with the parents border.